# How can I install the newest pan newsreader 0.147?

Tags: gnome, software-installation

Pan is as old as the internet almost, it is the only standalone newsreader client that runs on Linux that I can get to work, too many require a web browser. It was not maintained for a long time until now. However I had problems installing it with gmime 2.x dependencies.

```
configure: error: Package requirements (gmime-2.6 >= 2.6.20) were not met:
```

Answer (score 3):

there is (ironically not a usenet group) an email support list here

pan-users@nongnu.org

get pan source from
http://pan.rebelbase.com/

you might need , but probably not
https://download-fallback.gnome.org/sources/gmime/

```
./configure --with-gmime30 
make
sudo make install
```

they have fixed the error with 0.146 that made a mess out of the saved parts with ERRORS

another alternative suggested is

```
./configure --with-gnutls
```

Comment: You should find support on the group news.software.readers

Comment: ha, tried that and pan crashed, not handling previous newsgroup data well... could just be a quirk here.. still I am glad for unrar titled newsgroup posts to work properly, though many forget what a par file is for. also having problems with secure nntp server , and will work on that. there is always stunnel, another last millenium tool. I use a vpn in any case.

Comment: if anyone else has an issue with a download saving files with convoluted names , I sort by date, rename the first to a <name>.rar then use krusader's krename to rename to <name> and extention to r##{0}, there is a mouse hover help popup in the ext field. that explains that

Comment: @andrew, the last single post to that newsgroup ujs 2017 and then years before that. there is a new 0.148 version out now, just announced, that does not require the --config option.

Comment: right you are, downloading the group now, not crashing. 127,000 posts in  that group since the beginning of time, no since 2003. the future is the past.